# Math and nature, what's this shape?

Tags: geometry, math-history

(Almost) Every shape found in nature is pretty much described by math, either from Ancient Greeks or from today's Russians and so on. I saw this masterpiece built by a fish to attract a mate:

[image]

What's the name of this shape if any? For example a Platonic solid (no it's not)?

Comment: Things have names in math if they are referred to very often. This might not be referred to often enough for a common use term to have developed in the language/literature.

Comment: "today's Russians"... that's a good one!

Comment: The research first describing this can be found at http://www.nature.com/articles/srep02106 .

Comment: @BarryCipra shouldn't that amazing link you shared been posted as an answer? I see your point The Count. Barak, well, I smiled when I wrote it.. =)

Comment: @gsamaras, well, the link doesn't address your specific question, which I take to be whether the shape has a particular mathematical name.  It might be of interest to do a Fourier or wavelet analysis of the shapes, but that would require more detailed data.

Comment: BTW, this question reminds me of an old radio commercial from the 1970s, for a product I no longer remember.  The commercial was created by a comedy duo, whose names I also no longer recall.  It alluded to the movie *Jaws*, and the punch line, delivered in an agitated shriek, was, "The shark doesn't have a name!"

Comment: @BarryCipra indeed, but it's really interesting, thanks for sharing. It's amazing what the fish does! As for the commercial, born in 1992, I don't recall it either ;p

Comment: @gsamaras Why do you have deleted the last question ? I mean this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129458/how-to-prove-that-this-quantity-is-zero

Comment: Because it was downvoted @callculus, thus I thought that the community suggested I should deleted..

Comment: @gsamaras The downvotes for questions, and sometimes for answers, are often not comprehensible. I wouldn´t take the downvotes too seriously.  If you are still interested in an answer you can reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I can give an equation that produces this" and "this has a name" are not the same thing. I doubt this has a name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Stella. That might be the case, I was just wondering...